# Let $R > r > 0$ and $A = \{ (x,y,z): r^2 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq R^2\}$ show that $A$ is path-connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, path-connected

Let $R > r > 0$ and $A = \{(x,y,z): r^2 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq R^2\}$ show that $A$ is a path-connected.
A path from a point $x$ to a point $y$ in a topological space $X$ is a continuous function $ƒ$ from the unit interval $[0,1]$ to $X$ with $f(0) = x $ and $ f(1) = y$.

I can resolved that in $\Bbb R^2$ but i can´t find the path in $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: Hi Daniela,

This site does not receive questions that simply state a maths problem. It is a requirement that askers also include their thoughts/efforts in solving a problem. For example, it would be good to know if you know any results about path-connectivity, or if you've seen any similar questions solved before. Were there any strategies you tried in order to find $f$ (types of functions, geometric intuition, etc)? If you leave your question as is, it will be down-voted and closed, like your previous question.

Comment: Thanks i did not know that. However i present problem to find the funtion in $R^3$ipahave  a path in $R^2$ but a can´t make it in A. The path that i have is

Comment: That's good! How did you solve it in $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Note that there is an easy path joining any point in $A$ to the 'outer' surface, so, the problem reduces to showing that the outer shell is path connected. Furthermore, given any two points on the outer shell, you can find a 2d subspace containing those two points (and the origin, of course). Now use a 2d rotation to join those two points.

Comment: $(r_{1},\theta_{1})$ ,$(r_{2},\theta_{2})$ in $A$. Supposse that $r\leq r_{1} \leq r_{2} \leq R$\
Let $f(t)=(r_{1},(1-t)\theta_{1}+t \theta_{2})$ and $g(t)=((1-t)r_{1}+t r_{2},\theta_{2})$,this is my path in $R^2$

Comment: You should add this to your question to keep it self-contained, readers do not want to read comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | \|x\|=R \}$.

Given any point $x \in A$ the path $p(t) = (t {R \over \|x\|} +(1-t))x $ joins $x$ to the point ${R \over \|x\|}x \in S$.

So, we can presume that we have two points $x,y \in S$.
If the line joining $x,y$ passes through the origin, pick some other point $z \in S$ that is orthogonal to $x$. It is straightforward to show that
the segments $[x,z]$ and $[z,y]$ do not pass through the origin.

So, we can presume that the segment $[x,y]$ does not pass through the origin.

Then the path $p(t) = {R \over \|t y +(1-t)x\|}  (t y +(1-t)x)$ lies in $S$ and connects $x,y$.